# Grouping MFCCs from Frames

Tags: speech-recognition, mfcc

When calculating the MFCC for individual frames of an audio signal, is it sensible to generalize the matrix of MFCCs x number of time frames, to a single set of MFCCs for the signal? If yes, would that be through an average?

By sensible I mean, would the extent by which the accuracy of the information enveloped by the MFCC matrix be distorted/diminished through averaging, still allow for a reliable answer?

Comment: You need to expand "sensible"

Answer (score 0):

Any of the summary statistics may be used, mean, std, skew, kurtosis etc. One can also compute delta MFCC frames and then summary statistics over those as well. This might do OK for simple audio problems, but because temporal patterns are ignored by such a transformation it is of course limiting.

How much information is lost depends a lot on how long time window is used. And how much signal variation of interest there is during this time span. Which is very task dependent.

Separating rock from classical music should be quite doable with only MFCC summaries. Or male from female speech. But recognizing the words in a sentence very likely not.